# Control a dosing pump with raspberry pi zero w

Tags: dc-motor, raspberry-pi, l293d

Hi i have a few "Peristaltic Pump Dosing Pump 6V DC Motor" with the following specs:

```
DC: 6V
Non-load current: 100mA
```

So the idea was to control it with a `L293D` using the following scheme
[image]
Image source: https://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/controlling-dc-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi--cms-20051

But replacing the batteries with the following battery eliminator:

```
Adjustable output voltage: 3-12 V (DC)
600 mA output at 3/4,5/5 V
500 mA output at 6 V
480 mA output at 7,5 V
400 mA output at 9 V
300 mA output at 12 V
```

Would that work or do i need to add some additional components?
Also what V output do i need to set the battery eliminator to?

Comment: For this site you should provide the Fritzing schematic diagram rather than the wiring diagram. The schematic effectively shows us the scheme of the system and how it works. Your wiring diagram is to show (someone who doesn't understand electronics) how to wire it. In this case we don't know what the chip is doing.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks, sadly i think I'm one of the people who don't understand electronics :P, sadly the article i took the image from does not contain a Fritzing schematic diagram.

Comment: "battery eliminator" is quite a badass name for a power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fine. 4x AA batteries is 6 V, so set your power pack accordingly. There's plenty you can do to make this better, but this will get you started. One caution, double check your +6 V is not connected to the Pi, it is likely to damage or destroy it.

Comment: The pi will be powered by a usb charger! any chance you could list what could be done to improve this design?

Comment: @Peter It's fine as it is, especially for learning, but there are things like over voltage/current protection, decoupling etc to make it more robust to faults but you can deal with that when you go further in to the project :)

Comment: Do you have any examples how I could add over voltage/current protection?